# In fig we have a block (shape $A$) that a rod is connected to it (shape $B$)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

In fig we have a block (shape $A$) that a rod is connected to it (shape $B$)
[image] let that this system is stationary .
Now I know that free body diagram is :
[image]
Thus  $$A : \vec{i} :T_{BA}=f_{s}$$
$$A : \vec{j} :N_{A}=m_{A}g$$

And

$$B : \vec{i} :T_{AB}=m_{B}a=0  \ \ ????$$
$$B : \vec{j} :m_Bg=m_Ba =0 \ \ ????$$

According to my calculations $T_{AB}=T_{BA}$ must be zero  also $m_b=0$ but $m_{B}\neq 0$ also $T_{AB}=T_{BA}\neq 0$ .Where is my mistake?

Comment: Without an axial force on $B$, I don't see how your free body diagram can be right, since there are no horizontal forces on your body.  You certainly have vertical shear forces at the cut between $A$ and $B$ which are missing from your fbd.  You say you know your free body diagram is as shown but where is that knowledge coming from?

Answer (score 1):

To make things simple i assume block doesn't toggle and we really have an equilibrium as shown in question figure.

The rod will bend slightly in accordance with Euler-Bernoulli beam theory and the corresponding free body diagrams are: 
[image]
If you see any cross-section of rod the upper part is being stretched and lower is being compressed hence corresponding directions of tensions are opposite
At junction of box and rod , T<sub>1</sub> and -T<sub>1</sub> cancel . Hence no net horizontal force while an upward force of M<sub>b</sub>g acts hence vertical equilibrium is attained. And if you look carefully, torques about center of mass also vanish hence rotational equilibrium.
Looking at rod and a differential element in it :
[image]